# setSpan is not working

Tags: android

I am trying to add hyperlink on `textview` that's my code ..

```
if (hyperLinks.size()>0){
                    SpannableString text = new SpannableString(postContent);
                    for (int i = 0; i <hyperLinks.size() ; i++) {
                        int finalI = i;
                        ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                ProfileActivity.start(PostActivity.this,hyperLinks.get(finalI).getId());
                            }
                        };
                        text.setSpan(clickableSpan, hyperLinks.get(i).getStart(), hyperLinks.get(i).getStart()
                                , Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                    }

                    // make our ClickableSpans and URLSpans work
                    postContentTv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
                    postContentTv.setText(text, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
                    postContentTv.setClickable(true);
                }
```

that is not working , neither click nor color changed in the Texrview 
what's is the wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The start and end of the clickable area are exactly the same point, namely `hyperLinks.get(i).getStart()`, hence there is no area to click.

The problem lies in this line.

```
text.setSpan(clickableSpan,hyperLinks.get(i).getStart(),hyperLinks.get(i).getStart(),Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

The second `hyperLinks.get(i).getStart()` (the 3rd argument in the line of code above) should be something like `hyperLinks.get(i).getEnd()` assuming that you have implemented a getEnd() method. Otherwise it should be an Integer with at least a higher value than hyperLinks.get(i).getStart().